# Why does a column of 1s impact the results of a decision tree classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I was testing sklearn's `Pipeline` on a randomly generated classification problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, plot_tree
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

x, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=5, random_state=10)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.2, random_state=0)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('scale', StandardScaler()),
                       ('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)),
                       ('model', model)])
pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)

pipe_pred = pipe.predict(x_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, pipe_pred)
```

This results in an accuracy score of `.85`. However, when I change the `PolynomialFeatures` argument `include_bias` to `True`, which just inserts a single column of 1s into the array, the accuracy score becomes `.90`. For visualization, below I have plotted the individual trees for the results when bias is `True` and when `False`:

#### When `include_bias=True`: [True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYVUV.png)

#### When `include_bias=False`: [False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsqmd.png)

These images were generated by `plot_tree(pipe['model'])`.

The datasets are the same except when `include_bias=True` an additional column of 1s is inserted into column 0. So the column indexes for the `include_bias=True` data correspond to the `i + 1` column index in the `include_bias=False` data. (e.g. `with_bias[:, 5] == without_bias[:, 4]`)

Based on my understanding, the column of 1s shouldn't have an impact on the Decision Tree. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for `DecisionTreeClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html):

> **random_state : *int, RandomState instance, default=None***
> Controls the randomness of the estimator. The features are always randomly permuted at each split, even if `splitter` is set to `"best"`. When `max_features < n_features`, the algorithm will select max_features at random at each split before finding the best split among them. But the best found split may vary across different runs, even if `max_features=n_features`. That is the case, if the improvement of the criterion is identical for several splits and one split has to be selected at random. To obtain a deterministic behaviour during fitting, `random_state` has to be fixed to an integer. See Glossary for details.

You've set the `random_state`, but having a different number of columns will nevertheless make those random shuffles different.  Note that the value of `gini` is the same for both of your trees at each node, even though different features are making the splits.

Comment: just so I understand the `random_state` in the bigger picture of the sklearn `DecisionTreeClassifier` implementation assuming `max_features` is set to `None` which uses all features to create a split. Given that the gini's are the same but the feature used to split is different, the reason we get different results between Decision Trees using the exact same features but different `random_states` is ties because in the event there is a tie the `DecisionTreeClassifier` chooses one at random? Am I understanding this correctly?